# Why can I not source a file with the default cron installed on a debian wheezy server?

Tags: debian, cron

I use cron for years now. In order to load all my environment variables at once, I define them in a dedicated file (often but not always .bashrc) that I source in the crontab:

```
* * * * * (. /home/me/my_environment_variables.sh; my_script.sh)
```

Unfortunately, this trick fails to work with the debian wheezy server I've been recently asked to move to. More specifically, all happens as if the source command was ignored: my_script.sh is executed but with empty environment variable so that the results of the script are not the expected ones. I really don't understand the issue. Everything was perfectly working on my ubuntu

The installed cron package is "3.0pl1-124".

Have you any idea how to solve or to bypass this issue?

PS : Defining environmental variables in this way seems to work :

```
* * * * * (export OPTOS_HOME=/home/me/src/optos; my_script.sh)
```

However, defining more than one environment variables in this way is not convenient.

Comment: In what way does this fail to work? What errors do you get (check your local email)?

Comment: It fails to work in the way the environment variables are not defined .

Comment: I don't get any error message, neither by email nor in the /etc/var/syslog. All happens as if the source command was ignored: my_script.sh is executed but with empty environment variable so that the results of the script are not the expected ones. I really don't understand the issue. Everything was working perfectly on my ubuntu.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the command line, so that the shell will print each command as it is executed. You'll get a transcript in local email, post that. Is `/bin/sh` bash or dash? Do you have a line `SHELL=…` in the crontab file? Post the content of `my_environment_variables.sh`.

Comment: you should do `&&` instead of `;`: `. /path/env && /path/command`. `;` runs commands by different `sh`, so they do not see each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is an internal shell command. Check what shell is used by cron (by default it is /bin/sh).

Alternative solution is to create a wrapper script and put these commands inside. It will work for sure.

Comment: Not true. `man 5 crontab`: "The ``sixth'' field (the rest of the line) specifies the command to be run. The entire command portion of the line, up to a newline or % character, will be executed by /bin/sh or by the shell specified in the SHELL variable of the cronfile."

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to trace back some mistakes. To solve my problem, I've defined SHELL=/bin/bash and made some minor changes in my script. I've also replace '.' by the 'source' in the crontab, but I'm not sure this was necessary.